# Windows version 1809/build 17763 VM requirement

Tags: azure, azure-vm

I have a requirement of Windows version 1809/build 17763 VM on azure for some task. I choked and was not able to find the VM on azure. How can I setup windows VM with above version/build

Comment: `I have a requirement of Windows version 1809` why? That's an unsupported version. Windows 10 is a service offering, which means unless you run a Long-Term Support version, a version is only supported for around 18 months. What task do you want to run that requires an unsupported version of Windows 10?

Comment: How's going? Has your issue got resolved?

Answer (score 0):

You can [create a VHD with Windows OS version you need locally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/prepare-for-upload-vhd-image) then upload this VHD to Azure and use this VHD to create a managed image so that you can create VMs by this managed image.

For detailed steps [see this official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/upload-generalized-managed).

Btw, I noticed that there is a VM image based on windows server 1809, you can find it while creating VMs => see all images:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Windows 10 1809 is already out of support, so unless someone has an MSDN subscription or bought an LTS version, it's impossible to install 1809